# How can I add a local library in Gradle so that the program will be started?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have downloaded an external local javafx sdk library and am trying to make it work. However, it throws an error.

build.gradle

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'   
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'C:\\Program Files\\openjfx-17.0.7_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-17.0.7\\lib'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'ru.danteproject.App'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'C:\\Program Files\\openjfx-17.0.7_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-17.0.7\\lib', include: '*.jar')     
}
```

```java
package ru.danteproject;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        HelloController helloController;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
        launch();
    }
}



class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

> JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I tried various options I found on the internet, and also tried to use the configs I got as a result of a conversation with the GPT chat, but to no avail.

Comment: Why are you trying this approach that makes builds more error prone? Have you tried to build the JavaFX project using Gradle without downloading manually dependencies? The JavaFX getting started page shows instructions for Maven and Gradle: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle

Comment: You could try the [org.openjfx.javafxplugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin#javafx-gradle-plugin) plugin and [configure it to use a local SDK](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin#5-using-a-local-javafx-sdk).